# Where does a make program store its information?

Tags: dependencies, makefile, gnu-make

How exactly *make* knows if a file was modified or not, to run certain rules? This information must be in some place, so is there a file stored somewhere with timestamps from files?

There are a lot of *make* programs, thus I'm not sure if the principle behind dependency checking is the same for all of them. If they differ greatly, I'm mostly interested in GNU Make; though it would be good to know any of the differences.

Comment: It uses the `stat()` system call on the actual file names.  While it is running, it keeps tabs on the times of the files it works on, but it reestablishes the times each time it is run by looking at the file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make checks timestamps of inputs vs outputs. If a .o is older than a .c, for example, it assumes you must have edited it and the .o needs to be remade.

Comment: So it was that easy, eh? Surprisingly enough, I couldn't arrive in this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Compare the timestamp ON the source file (date modified, date created etc. are stored as part of the file info) and on the output file (the executable, or the object file). If the source file is "newer", then recompile.

Sometimes when there are wrong timestamps on my source files e.g. I edit them on a computer on which the date was set in the future, then I just `touch *` my source files to change the timestamp and it works.

Answer (score 1):

It reads timestamps in real time from the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way of doing this is used by [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) only if it is requested via `build_check target_newer`.  This is because network filesystems don't always agree on timestamps and they can get modified when you copy a file.  Also file systems with seconds-precision (FAT even 2s) are still wide spread.  A lot can happen in that time nowadays.

Therefore makepp calculates a smart signature of the content (excluding comments and unimportant white space, e.g. for the C family of languages).  This is then stored in `.makepp/yoursourcename.mk` and will be picked up next time to see if something significant changed.  The smart signatures of all dependencies (which are auto detected btw.) as well as the command string and a few other details then decide if a rebuild is needed.

*There is much more to makepp.  Besides doing almost all that GNU make can, there are lots more useful things, and you can even extend your makefiles with some Perl programming.*